# Setting height in a responsive slider (jQuery Cycle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cycle

I'm using jQuery Cycle for a few slides, with content below it. jQuery Cycle sets the parent to relative and the child slides to absolute, so the content that should be below it is covered. Typically, I would give the parent container a height to solve my problem.

Since the layout is responsive, the height can change. Is there a simple solution out there for this?

EDIT:

Here's what wound up doing it for me:

```
$(window).load(function(){

    var rotate_height = $('#rotate div img').height();
    $('#rotate').css('height', rotate_height);

    $(window).resize(function() {
        if($(window).width() >= 960){
            rotate_height = 290;
            $('#rotate').css('height', rotate_height);
            $('#rotate').cycle('next');
        } else if ($(window).width() >= 768 && $(window).width() <= 959) {
            rotate_height = 230;
            $('#rotate').css('height', rotate_height);
            $('#rotate').cycle('next');
        } else if ($(window).width() >= 480 && $(window).width() <= 767) {
            rotate_height = 210;
            $('#rotate').css('height', rotate_height);
            $('#rotate').cycle('next');
        } else if ($(window).width() <= 479) {
            rotate_height = 150;
            $('#rotate').css('height', rotate_height);
            $('#rotate').cycle('next');
        }
    });

    $('#rotate').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        fit: 1,
        containerResize: 0,
        slideResize: 0,
        height: rotate_height       
    });
});
```

cycle('next') forces the slide to the next after a visitor resizes their monitor. Not ideal, but the images wouldn't scale back up, only after a slide change.

Comment: Some sample codes would be helpful.

Comment: Glad the conceptual 'nudge' was enough to steer you to a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and [`resize`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) events to trigger a function which will set the [`height`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) appropriately based on the [`width`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) of the `window`. As the page 'responds' to the current window width, your jQuery method will appropriately size the height of the slideshow's parent.

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.cycle-container').each(function(){      
        $(this).height($(this).find('> *:first').outerHeight());
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, solved it like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="hp_slider">
<a href="#"><img class="slide" alt="" width="940" height="420" src="/assets/images/cache/17dd0cc96316523cbba09777c8e512769078b0bc.png" /></a>
<a href="#"><img class="slide" alt="" width="940" height="420" src="/assets/images/cache/39fbcef502bd01b7f13980a81b73f6e6cb5491b6.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hp_slider {margin-bottom:49%; width:100%; height:auto;}
.hp_slider img {width:100%; height:auto;}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.hp_slider').cycle({
fx: 'fade',
containerResize: false,
slideResize: false,
fit: 1
});
});
```

It's a little dirty, but the margin-bottom as a percentage pushes the text down from behind the slider and keeps it in place at different sizes so it's still responsive.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do this:

```
$slideshow.cycle({ 
  containerResize: false,
  slideResize: false,
  fit: 1
});
```

basically, when window resizes, the slide container is forced to resized.
(not sure if you should set all to true or false, please give it a try.)

Comment: I already have this code in my similar project but still not working.